# create a view according to url pattern

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

i'm creating a complex application similiar to a social network and based on ExtJs framework. I need to have specific url for each performable action, so for example, the edit user action will have the url www.mynet.com/editprofile?id=425 **associated** with the *user_edit.js* view

My ExtJs project is based on MVC pattern, so i've an **app.js** that is launched at the very beginning, a series of controller, views and store/model.
In my app.js file i thought to manually check the called url, and according to it, instantiate (Ext.create) a specified view. This solution works fine but what i want to know is if exists an "offical" system to do that provided by the framework itself.

A way that allow me to map urls/paths with specific views like:

```
    '/' -> Controller_home.showHome()
    '/users/edit' -> Controller_user.showEditUser(user_id)
    ...and so on
```

Comment: http://existdissolve.com/2011/08/extjs-4-a-modified-ext-util-history/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an 'official' system for this : Ext.util.History.

This allows you to have URLs with a hash, like `www.mynet.com/#editprofile?id=425` (notice the hash sign).

But you have still to write the code that

- updates the url on each action
- and, on page load or history change, interprets the URL to bring the ui into the required state.